# change a column to unique - sqlite3.OperationalError: near "UNIQUE": syntax error

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I have been trying to change an existing column to unique, but I kept getting this error: `sqlite3.OperationalError: near "UNIQUE": syntax error`

Here is my sql: `ALTER TABLE tableName ADD UNIQUE (colName);`

Answer (score 0):

Just make a unique index on the column.

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_colName ON tableName(colName);
```

Sqlite's [`ALTER TABLE`](https://sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html) doesn't support adding constraints to existing columns.